How to export obj with texture coordinates and mapping applied to image textures?
I have an object with multiple image textures applied to different faces. In the shader editor, I added a mapping node and a texture coordinate node to change the scale/positions of the images on the object. When I try exporting it as a Wavefront obj., the changes I made don't stay. How can I apply the coordinates permanently? I am importing into MaxMSP.
I have already tried File>External Data>Pack Resources

Read through https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures
